# Lucene 4.10.1, IndexWriterConfig initialisation error

Tags: java, android, lucene

I'm trying to implement a very basic search in pdf functionnality in my app,

For this , I'm adding lucene using maven in a new project, and use this code :

```
final String _sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
public void pdfIndex(){
    try {
        new File(_sdcard+"/techlist/data/pdfindex").mkdir();
        Directory d=new SimpleFSDirectory(new File(_sdcard+"/techlist/data/pdfindex"));
        Analyzer analyzer=new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig iwc=new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST,new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LATEST));
        iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

        IndexWriter writer=new IndexWriter(d,iwc);
        Document document= LucenePDFDocument.getDocument(new File(_sdcard + "/myapp/data/examplefile.pdf"));
        writer.addDocument(document);
        writer.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
    }
}
```

All compile fine but when I run this code, I have this error in the logcat output :

```
10-10 16:39:51.071    1356-1356/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:125)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:171)
    at ludo.testing_maven.MyActivity.pdfIndex(MyActivity.java:38)
    at ludo.testing_maven.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.loadNextProfile(SPIClassIterator.java:112)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.hasNext(SPIClassIterator.java:128)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:64)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:125)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:171)
    at ludo.testing_maven.MyActivity.pdfIndex(MyActivity.java:38)
    at ludo.testing_maven.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:49)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.loadNextProfile(SPIClassIterator.java:112)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.hasNext(SPIClassIterator.java:128)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:64)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:125)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:171)
    at ludo.testing_maven.MyActivity.pdfIndex(MyActivity.java:38)
    at ludo.testing_maven.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your pom.xml, it looks like you miss dependency, that's why you get ClassNotFound